# .htacess url rewrite rule to shortern the url and remove "?st_id=" from it

Tags: .htaccess

I currently goto:

```
support-requests/?st_id=7
```

Ideally i would like to just go straight here using .htaccess url-rewriting to make the page neater to look at and navigate to without the "?st_id=" being displayed in the url.

```
support-requests/7
```

This is what i currently have but i know its wrong and it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule support-requests/ support-requests/%1/%2/?
```

Could i have some assistance in getting this correct please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^support-requests/([^/]*)$ /support-requests/?st_id=$1 [L]
```

Should leave you with:

`www.example.com/support-requests/7`

Comment: That is perfect thanks for the help on this, its been driving me crazy all day :)

Comment: Glad I could help :-)